# Angular FxFlex Layout

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I'm learning FxFlex instead of using Bootstrap, along with Angular Material. And, I'm pulling my hair out. Not a lot of documentation and examples online and the ones that exist aren't as helpful. The system seems fairly easy but it's confounding me.

Basically, I have a table and a button. I'd like to place the button on the right of the page and the table below it. I can't seem to move the button to the right of the screen using FxFlex. In bootstrap I'd use float or col-offset but here a grid system isn't really available.

I see tutorials on spacing a group of items but not a single itemm.

I'm looking for a grid like experience.

Below is not actual code, just aprox. But the concept is the same. Create column container. Inside create a row, maybe with wrap. Then inside that have items and in each item you can use fxFlex="" to modify size / placement. None of this allows me to place a button at the right side of the page

```
<div fxLayout="column">
  <div fxFlexLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need a grid layout, why not use CSS grid?

Comment: Consider that @angular/flex-layout is in beta since forever and its bad idea to use such libraries in production environment... Also why use library for styling with attributes when you have stylesheets just use proper styles like css grid.

Comment: Thanks. After frustration with angular-flex, I'm moving to CSS grid. Basically I wanted a minimal class structure to align things. But, not all the bootstrap extras

Comment: Angular Flex-Layout does offer the ability to use CSS grids since [`6.0.0-beta.16`](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-beta16-2018-06-07). See the [API documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation) for more info.

Comment: The `fxFlexOffset` property is used to offset an element [(Wiki)](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlexOffset-API).
And here is a demo link for Flex-Layout [(Demo)](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs).

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
<div fxFlexLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
   <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div fxFlexLayout="row-reverse">
   <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

when in the page you have many div with flex layout you can change order of div for change place in page with **fxFlexOrder**

Answer (score 0):

"fxFlexLayout" is not a directive, imparts no rules, and it's not in the documentation. You meant fxLayout. Also, when you use fxLayoutAlign on an element, fxLayout isn't necessary. FxLayout gives you css rules you already get in fxLayoutAlign, namely: flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;

The code you wrote above actually works, by the way. But this is sufficient to get what you want.

```
    <div fxLayout="column">
      <div fxLayoutAlign="end">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```